# Creating a random generated array with a fixed number of elements, but still less than a fixed amount

Tags: arrays, perl

newbie here, as the title says I'm trying to generate an array that has to contain random numbers (including negative ones), but no more than 19.
I came up with this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

my @rand=();

my $all_the_numbers=int(rand(19));

my $i=0;

while ($all_the_numbers<20)
{
    my $number=20-int(rand(30));  #in order to randomize negative numbers too
    push @rand, $number;
    $i++;
    last if $i=$all_the_numbers;
}
say "@rand";
```

But I always end up with an array that has only one element. Any idea why?

**UPDATE**

First of all, thanks for helping me with the previous problem.
Now I'm trying to delete every positive number in the array, making it contain only the negative ones; the whole program looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use 5.10.1;

my @rand=();

my $all_the_numbers=int(rand(19));

my $i=0;

while ($all_the_numbers<20)
{
 my $number=20-int(rand(30));
 push @rand, $number;
 $i++;
 last if $i==$all_the_numbers;
}
say "@rand";

my $h=0;

while ($all_the_numbers<20)
{
 for (@rand)
 {
 if ($rand[0]<0)
  {
   next;  #in order to make it skip the negative ones
  }
   shift @rand;
 }
 $h++;
 last if $h==$all_the_numbers;
}
say "@rand";
```

However, this resoults in deleting only the positive numbers that come before the first negative one in the array, leaving what comes right after untouched...
So, how is it that the while loop doesn't keep on deleting the positives?
Here's a picture to better explain myself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi7sf.png
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for numerical comparison

Comment: `my @rand = map { 20 - int(rand(30)) } 0..int(rand(19))` might be a bit easier.

Comment: If you have a new question, it should go in a new question. Please remove the new question from here, create a new question, paste it there, and then you may get a better response. You can reference this question in your follow-on if you want, but that's not strictly required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    last if $i==$all_the_numbers;
```

Observe the operator `==`.

You probably knew it already, but for the benefit of other readers that might visit:

- The operator `==` compares for equality.
- The operator `=` *assigns* the value on its right to the variable on its left.